# reasons and fixes for MSB8008 error

Tags: msbuild

What can be the possible reasons of the MSB8008 error be and how to fix it?

For example a error message of this is:

```
 error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is an indication for a version conflict of multiple msbuild evironments. 
To fix this searching and using the absolute path of the right msbuild helped for me.